# htaccess redirect based on referrer URL string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, security, referrer

I have a 3rd party who passes traffic to my website.

Sometimes they use a string in their url like:

```
https://referrer.com/embed/section.htm?bikes=1
```

If the referrer passes traffic to me with the argument `bikes=1` I'd like to serve up a different page.

How can I do this (I know this question has been done to death but I can't see an example that matches my question.)

### EDIT

I've tried editting .htaccess with the following but it breaks access to the entire site (with a 500 error)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\.referrer\.(.*)\(*bikes*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/bikes [L,R]
```

### Another Edit!

Here's an example of an access.log entry where the 3rd party is posting to my site:

```
 90.xxx.xxx.xxx- - [21/Oct/2019:15:03:51 +0000] "POST /products HTTP/1.1" 200 23505 "https://referrer.com/embed/products.htm?bikes=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

So, they're `POST`ing to my `/products` page.  I want to redirect this to `/bikes` retaining the `POST` data (using 307 as suggested by @DeanTaylor

I've tested this out using some mod_rewrite testing tools but can't get the correct syntax.

Comment: You can achieve it with server-side code (like php) as well as using htaccess. In php you can use `$_GET` to access query string and in htaccess you can write rewrite-condition. Come back with your initial effort.

Comment: Hmm, after reading a bit more into it, I think what I need might not be achievable.  The 3rd party is POSTing data to me.  If I initiate a conditional redirect, I think I'll lose the POST - is this correct?

Comment: To me it is unclear if you are talking about the URL actually requested from you or about the referrer URL. Those two are something quite different.

Comment: The referrer posts to my site. I want to redirect to a different page depending on the contents of the referrer URL

Comment: @Huskie69 you can use "307 Temporary Redirect" via `[R=307,L]` to cause the browser to re-submit the same POST data to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks @DeanTaylor - I'm trying to do this with my htaccess file but not having any luck.  I've even use a mod_rewrite expression tester and I just can't seem to get the syntax correct - https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=94db76c4-efd0-50bf-a46b-c7f01dd78259